# Converting a JSON String from a datatable into a JObject c#

Tags: json, api, post, json.net

I am looking for some help with a  datatable conversion into a JObject. I am using `C#` in visual studio along with the `Newtonsoft JSON .net` library. I have retrieved my datatable from my database.

From here I took the data table and processed it through this class:

```
    public string DataTableToJSONString(DataTable table)
    {
        string JSONString = string.Empty;
        JSONString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(table,Formatting.Indented);
        return JSONString; 
    }
```

Now that the object has been converted to a `JSONString` successfully (It throws no errors at this point) via the `Newtonsoft JSON.net` Library, I am unable to parse it into a `JObject` with this code:

> Note: "json" is the string variable I placed the returned value from the DatatabletoDataTableToJSONString() method into..

JObject job = JObject.Parse(json);

I continuously get the following error...

```
Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: StartArray. Path '', line 1, position 1.
```

The reason I need it in the form of a `JObject` it to pass it into the following post method for an API:

```
    public static async Task<JObject> Post(string url, JObject data)
    {
        // Create an HttpClient instance
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = CreateBasicHeader(ClientContext.Username, ClientContext.Password);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));   

        // Send a request asynchronously and continue when complete
        var requestbody = new StringContent(data.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url, requestbody);
        dynamic content = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<JObject>();

        // Check that response was successful or throw exception
        try
        {
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Status Code: " + response.StatusCode +    "\r\nMessage: " + content[0].ToString(), ex);
        }

        // Read response asynchronously as a JObject

        return content;
    }
```

I would appreciate any help on this as I have been researching for 2 weeks with no luck. This one is really killing me. Thanks in advance to all who take the time to examine this.

UPDATE: I ended up adding in the following bit of code as I realized I was returning an array when I pulled the data table.

string jsonresult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt);

```
        JArray aray = JArray.Parse(jsonresult);
```

//I then have code for the API login credentials here....

```
            foreach (JObject item in aray)
            {
                ApiClient.Post(Url, item).Wait();
            }
```

This appears to pass in the JObjects just fine into the post method although I get the following error:"AggregateException was unhandled..." I set a break point and the flaw appears to happen at the:

```
        try
        {
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        }
```

After attempting the response.ensuresuccessstatusCode(); The program of course jumps to the catch....

```
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Status Code: " + response.StatusCode + "\r\nMessage: " + content.message.ToString(), ex);
        }
```

Again, any help would be appreciated. I am almost there with this. After it posts, I will be done.... Thanks again in advance to everyone. I apologize for being long winded.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that [JSON](http://json.org/) has two types of containers: arrays and objects:

- An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs. An object begins with { (left brace) and ends with } (right brace).

  The corresponding [LINQ to JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) class is [`JObject`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm).
- An array is an ordered collection of values. An array begins with [ (left bracket) and ends with ] (right bracket). Values are separated by , (comma).

  The corresponding LINQ to JSON class is [`JArray`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JArray.htm).

So, how does Json.NET serialize a data table?  From the documentation [Serialize a DataSet](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeDataSet.htm), we can see that each table is serialized as an array.

If you attempt to parse a JSON string whose root object is an array into a `JObject`, you will get this exception.

Instead, you must return a `JArray`, or better yet a [`JToken`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Methods_T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken.htm) which is the root class for all JSON entities:

```
    public static async Task<JToken> Post(string url, JObject data)
    {
        // Create an HttpClient instance
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = CreateBasicHeader(ClientContext.Username, ClientContext.Password);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));   

        // Send a request asynchronously and continue when complete
        var requestbody = new StringContent(data.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url, requestbody);
        dynamic content = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<JToken>();

        // Check that response was successful or throw exception
        try
        {
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Status Code: " + response.StatusCode +    "\r\nMessage: " + content[0].ToString(), ex);
        }

        // Read response asynchronously as a JToken

        return content;
    }
```

Comment: This was helpful. I realized the data table was being returned in an array format. I parsed it out and passed each JObject within the array into my post method but the problem is not completely solved yet. Thanks for pointing that out for me :)

Answer (score 0):

I am answering this thread and closing it as the original question has technically been answered. I simply converted the JArray into its respective JObjects with the following bit of code.

foreach (JObject item in aray)
            {
                ApiClient.Post(Url, item).Wait();
            }

Although I am still working on debugging, I was technically able to pull the Object out of the array that I got from the data table.

Thanks all!!!!!